# "Subquery returns more than 1 row" with no subquery MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webapp that when a link for a document is clicked, a PHP script is called that updates the "viewed" status for the document in the DB. This is the script that is called when the click happens:

```
<?php
include '../../variables.php';

// The document that is passed through POST
$document = $_POST['document'];

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $db);

if (!$conn){
    die('Could not connect to db: '.mysqli_error($conn));
}

$sql = "UPDATE files
        SET docViewed = '1'
        WHERE fileloc = '$document'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query){
    die('Could not update docViewed: '.mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

As you can see, I have no subquery in the MySQL query that updates the field I want, yet I still am receiving this error:

> Could not update docViewed: Subquery returns more than 1 row

I have tried appending to the query:

```
"...
WHERE fileloc = '$document'
LIMIT 1";
```

However, I still get the same result.

To be clear, each `$document` has to be UNIQUE in the database, so there are no duplicate entries.

**UPDATE:** This post is not a duplicate of the suggested post, as that OP is using a subquery. In this example, I am not using a subquery anywhere.

Here is the structure of the `files` table I use. Also to show there is no duplicate of `$document`, I filtered the table by the `fileloc` which is `30294/1506012960606.pdf`:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I have narrowed down the actual MySQL query that is happening to produce this error:

```
UPDATE files
SET docViewed = '1'
WHERE fileloc = '30294/1492682311085.pdf'
```

Comment: Wierd error are you sure files is a table and not a view?

Comment: Files is indeed its own table

Comment: It isn't a duplicate because in that post, the OP is actually using a subquery. I am not

Comment: @mega6382, you are a bit too fast with that duplicate

Comment: echo and check what you get in $document. Or else echo $sql to see the query created.

Comment: `$document` could very well be a subquery. Where does it come from? Be aware that you might me subject to SQL Injection!

Comment: @LuanNico `$document` is not a subquery, it is a string value: `30294/1506012960606.pdf` which is simply the location of the file and how it is stored in the DB

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a **trigger** in that table? Maybe the trigger is producing that error.

Comment: Can you please edit with your table structure?

Comment: Please add    SHOW COLUMNS FULL FROM files;   in your question.

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan okay, I updated

Comment: Run the following command: `SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE files'`

Comment: How about just using your "as f" in your query?  UPDATE files as f SET f.docViewed = '1' WHERE f.fileloc = '$document'; to avoid mixups.

Comment: You are using `OOP` right? Just to make sure. And I agree with @Nic, you can use you “as f”,.

Comment: if you log out your sql string what does it look like? Also i might be missing something, but why are you aliasing a table  when you don't use the alias as a prefix anywhere?

Comment: Have updated my question to show the exact query being run that is producing the error

Comment: Or you can simply write `UPDATE files SET docViewed = '1' WHERE fileloc = '$document'`

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan even removing the alias does not change the result

Comment: SELECT * FROM files WHERE fileloc = '30294/1492682311085.pdf'  returns only 1 result?

Comment: Write `die($sql);` right after `$sql` statement, run it and tell us what it returns, please.

Comment: @Nic Yes, that query returns 1 row, the row I want to update

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan it returns this `Status: UPDATE files
  SET docViewed = '1'
  WHERE fileloc = '30294/1506012960606.pdf'`

Comment: What about **triggers**? Does the table have any??

Comment: If you are using OOP why is not entirely as OOP? The `if(!$conn)` is for PDO.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: It does, however the triggers don't have anything to do with ON/BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE. They only revolve around INSERTs

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't change too much, but adds some more logging points to maybe drill down on where the issue is. I updated your mysqli usage to the object oriented approach, as well as parameterizing the queries using prepared statement (always good to avoid sql injection, but in this case extra practical because it lets us test the query in several steps).

```
<?php
try {
    include '../../variables.php';

    // The document that is passed through POST
    $document = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'document', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $db);

    if ($conn->connect_error){
        throw new Exception("({$conn->errno}) {$conn->error}");
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE files
            SET docViewed = '1'
            WHERE fileloc = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception("({$conn->errno}) {$conn->error}");
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $document);
    $exec = $stmt->execute();

    if (!$exec) {
        throw new Exception($stmt->error);
    } else if ($stmt->affected_rows === 0) {
        throw new Exception('No file location found');
    }


} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e);
    die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```